# Change default library path for one session only in R

Tags: r

I created a project-specific library installing all required packages using:

`install.packages("dplyr", lib = "<random folder>")`

I want my script to use functions (for this session only) from that specific `<random folder>` using double colon, e.g `dplyr::group_by()`

Is there a way to do this?

*! Let us ignore the option to use `miniCRAN` or `renv` for now.*

Comment: `library()` also takes a `lib.loc` argument & will load the package as installed there

Comment: I do not want to explicitly load the package using `library()`, but use double-colon operator `::` instead.

Comment: Does loading the package with `library()` and then double-colon `::` will use the correct version of the package and it's functions (namespace)?

Comment: Yes `library` works. `loadNamespace` would as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in R that load packages do so by querying the active library paths, as provided by `.libPaths()`:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Users/kevinushey/Library/R/4.0/library"
[2] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library"
```

You can customize the library paths used in a particular session with the same function -- just pass it the library paths you wish to use. For example:

```
> dir.create("~/r-lib")
> .libPaths("~/r-lib")
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Users/kevinushey/r-lib"
[2] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library"
```

Then `library()`, `::` and so on will load packages from those library paths.

Note that system-wide and site-wide library paths will always be appended to your requested library paths -- see `?.libPaths` for more details.